# Fail if type is not provided to builder, unless type is ()

Tags: rust, types

I'm creating an interface which builds a runner over a generic trait implementer:

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc::Sender;

trait Poll {
    type Output;
    type Config: 'static;

    fn poll(cfg: Self::Config, tx: Sender<Self::Output>) -> !;
}

struct Runner<P: Poll>(P, Option<P::Config>);

impl<P: Poll> Runner<P> {
    fn run(poller: P) -> Self {
        Self(poller, None)
    }
    
    fn with_config(mut self, cfg: P::Config) -> Self {
        self.1 = Some(cfg);
        self
    } 
    
    fn on(mut self, tx: Sender<P::Output>) -> ! {
        let config: P::Config = {
            todo!()
        };
        
        P::poll(config, tx);
    }
}
```

I would like `on` to fail in some way if the user doesn't provide a config to the builder. I would also like `with_config` to be optional if `P::Config == ()`.

I think I can do this through determining the type of the config through `std::any::TypeId`, but I'm not sure if it's safe to convert a unit to a generic like this afterwards.

```rust
use std::any::TypeId;
let config: P::Config = {
    if let Some(config) = self.1 {
        config
    } else if TypeId::of::<P::Config>() == TypeId::of::<()>() {
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute_copy(&()) }
    } else {
        panic!("no config :(")
    }
};
```

Comment: Not sure about the future, but at least currently miri doesn't complain about this. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c7e0d42a8a4221b05345cc1ef601c1c4). (I removed the `-> !` just so the test can end in a reasonable time)

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues miri accepting it does not mean it's sound, neither does miri complaining mean it contains UB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better way to do this would be to encode the type of the provided config in the type of the `Runner` and have it default to `()`.  Give `Runner` a second generic parameter for the type of the config, and only bound on `P: Poll` when it's required (for `Runner::on`) and there you can enforce that `P::Config` is the same type as the config type parameter:

```
use std::sync::mpsc::Sender;

trait Poll {
    type Output;
    type Config: 'static;

    fn poll(cfg: Self::Config, tx: Sender<Self::Output>) -> !;
}

struct Runner<P, C>(P, C);

impl<P> Runner<P, ()> {
    fn run(poller: P) -> Self {
        Self(poller, ())
    }
}

impl<P, C1> Runner<P, C1> {
    fn with_config<C2>(self, cfg: C2) -> Runner<P, C2> {
        Runner(self.0, cfg)
    }
}

impl<P, C> Runner<P, C>
where
    P: Poll<Config = C>,
{
    fn on(self, tx: Sender<P::Output>) -> ! {
        P::poll(self.1, tx);
    }
}
```

A few things to note about this approach:

- `()` is the default config type, so if you are using a `Poll` where `Config` is `()` then there is no need to call `with_config`.
- You call `with_config` to replace the config with another one, possibly of a different type, which discards the prior config.
- The bound on the `impl` providing `Runner::on` statically guarantees that the config is of the correct type for the given `Poll` implementation. *This makes it impossible to even invoke `on` if the config is missing!*

In my opinion, this gives you exactly the result you want, but without any possibility to panic at runtime and without any `unsafe` hacks.  A configuration simply can't be missing, but defaults to `()`, giving you the desired ergonomics of omitting a `with_config` call when that's the type of `Poll::Config`.

Comment: This is a really great answer, I'll reword the question and accept it.